# How can I create a Container component in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have multiple components built and  each component is using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` to retrieve data from the store and dispatch actions. I want to combine them all in a single container and use that container.

For ex:

**Home Component**

```
class Home extends React.Component{

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addToCart: (id) => {dispatch(addToCart(id))}
    }
}
```

and **Cart Component**

```
class Cart extends React.Component{

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addToCart: (id) => {dispatch(addToCart(id))}
    }
}
```

So, here I want to combine both of them and use a single container passed each of the components.

Comment: Great, what have you tried?

Comment: That can be done using HOC. Have you tried to create one?

Comment: No, I have not used any higher order components. Could you please help me how I can create one?

Comment: I have tried to create **HomeContainer** class and tried to move the mapStateToProps into that class and use the import of the class in the **Home** component, but I stuck in the middle on how to pass props from the container to class component.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform that by use `redux-store` connect function only on the `ContainerComponent` and pass to each child props which the Container has receive from the store.

```
const mapPropsToState = (state) => {
    items: state.items,
    // .... other properties
}
connect(mapPropsToState, mapDispatchToProps)(ContainerComponent);

export class ContainerComponent extends Component {
    render = () => <div>
        <Child2Component items={this.props.item} />
        <Child2Component items={this.props.item} />
        // .... other component which need to access props receive from Store
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Hi Yves Kipondo, how can I use those props passed to **Child2Component** in the class component. I am trying access them by **this.props.items**. Is that correct?

Comment: And could you also suggest me how to dispatch actions by using containers.

Comment: Exactly that is the right way to use that props. Dispatch action will be use exactly the same way as props